# Adding Cookie To Simple jQuery Function

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

So I have this *extremely* simple jQuery function...
My question is, how do I add a cookie when the DIV is hidden (i.e. faded out)? I want the cookie to be active until browser or window close.

In short, when a "visitor" clicks a specified X on a DIV (i.e. class .updateCloseBTN), it will hide the DIV. But if the user refreshes or revisits the page, the DIV will be shown again. If the user closes the DIV via the function below, it should not be loaded again, regardless if the user refreshes or revisits the page. However, it the user closes the browser window or browser itself and return the site, it will appear...

```
// Update Prompt: Hide on 'X' click 
$('.updateCloseBTN').click(function () {
    $('.upgradeWrap').fadeOut(400);
});
```

Comment: **EDITED** original post @VIDesignz

Comment: You'll need a plugin like this :) https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, You'll need a plugin like this :) https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Once you get the plugin...

Create your cookie function

```
function setsomecookie(){
     $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 365 });
}
```

Use a callback for the fadeOut() animation.

```
$('.updateCloseBTN').click(function () {
    $('.upgradeWrap').fadeOut(400, setsomecookie);
});
```

This will run the 'setsomecookie' function after the fadeOut() is complete :)

Comment: So what do I put in `// Stuff, stuff & more stuff`?

Comment: Problem is I'm not too sure how to create the cookie. That's where I'm stuck. Function arrangement I can do. :)

Comment: Ooohhhh, I thought you just wanted to know how to trigger a function when the fadeOut() was complete.

Comment: @MikeBarwick You'll need a plugin like this :) https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: @MikeBarwick Check this post, it will help you once you get the plugin :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Comment: Cheers man! Put your comments as an answer and I'll "check" ya ;)

Comment: Oh, you didn't need to fill it out. Just meant your comments, but this works lol.